# Fail on installing mysql server 8.0 on windows 10

Tags: mysql, installation, failed-installation

[MySQL server installation fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gcCb.png)

I have already installed visual studio 2017 but got this error every time, even when I install mysql server 5.7 . Anyone know to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us some more info?

Did you try closing all background apps and checked the firewall?
Did you use the MSI-installer or something else?
Did you run it as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I close malwarebytes, run as administrator, install visual studio 2015 and 2017, have all the visual c++ redistributables 2015 and it still fails somehow.

Comment: By closing all background apps I also mean stuff like xampp, TeamViewer,... and did you try installing it via the command line? A few times I had the same issue and doing it via command line worked for some reason

Comment: Thank you. I installed it through choco and now it works perfectly.

Comment: For the ones who are still getting this error: install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685 and Python 3.7 before run the installer. This should solve the problem.